# Not getting route params after navigating via react-router-4

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4

after navigating via `this.props.history.push` i don't get `route params` in the `component`.

i have the single `component` that is getting rendered on both routes.

So going from one route to another is resulting `component update` and i am not getting the `route params` in it.

if refresh the page i get the `route params`

```
this.props.history.push(`/pois/select/${lastAction.payload.poiID}`)
```

my routing component.

```
  class Routes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
            <Switch >
                <Route exact path="/pois/" component={ POIS } mode='view' />
                <Route exact path="/pois/select/:poiID" component={ POIS } mode='select' />
                <Route exact path="/pois/create" component={ POIS } mode='create'/>
                <Route exact path="/pois/update/:poiID" component={ POIS } mode='update'/>
            </Switch>
       </div>;
  }
```

Comment: where you are printing the name of params ? use `componentWillReceiveProps` life method and use `console.log(nextProps.params)` it will print the value. like this `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
 console.log(nextProps.params)
}`

Comment: @MayankShukla 
i can see the url updating, console logging in the component shows that `this.props.match.params` is an empty object `{}`

Comment: @MayankShukla
i can see the params in `componentWillReceiveProps` but cannot see then in a functions invoked from `componentWillUpdate` 

i want to check whether the mode is changed or not before doing and `ajax` so i need `prevprops`

Comment: do you want to make the ajax call on route change as well as on initial rendering ?

Comment: @MayankShukla, yes. and i can't because the ID is blank.
i not am getting the new params in `componentWillReceiveProps`, `componentDidUpdate's` `prevprops` nor in `componentWillUpdate's` nextProps... not in `this.props`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the combination of `componentWillReceiveProps` and `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

When first time component renders do the api call inside `componentDidMount` method, and fetch the data, like this:

```
componentDidMount(){
   // ajax call to fetch data then do setState to store in state variable
}
```

Next time when any thing changes in props, `componentWillReceiveProps` method will get called, do the api call in that, like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
     console.log(nextProps.params, this.props.params);
  // nextProps.params will print the new params values
  // this.props.params will print the old params values
  // ajax call to fetch data then do setState to store in state variable
}
```